How can I connect two hosts behind CGNAT with wireguard using an untrusted VPS?
I have a home network behind CGNAT and I would like to connect to it over wireguard from the internet on my phone, also behind CGNAT. My ISPs don’t support IPv6.
Since neither side will have a public IP address, I have a VPS which does have a public IP address.
I have set up wireguard on the server and the client.
I don’t want to have wireguard running on the VPS to act as an intermediary as it is not fully under my control, and its private key would allow access to my home network.
I think what I want is some sort of UDP relay running on the VPS forwarding encrypted wireguard packets between the two hosts. So the connection between the server and the client remains end to end encrypted and the VPS remains untrusted.
I think this must be possible with some iptables masquerading rules on the VPS. There is an answer at https://forum.mikrotik.com/viewtopic.php?t=210772 for mikrotik routers, but I want something for iptables. I also don’t know how wireguard “listens” for these packets. An alternative might be “wireguard in wireguard” but this seems unnecessary.
Had anyone done something like this?

I don’t mind having a relay running on the VPS; I just don’t want it to be able to decrypt the packets.

tailscale, netbird, zerotier, twingate, netmaker - etc https://forums.lawrencesystems.com/t/overlay-networks-tailscale-netbird-netmaker-zerotier/19817

Assuming you are willing to use two tunnels there are two ways you can configure them:
Connected
Meaning both tunnels terminate on the VPS.
As you point out, this means that the VPS will have keying material and unencrypted traffic - which is not desirable.
Wrapped
The first (outer) tunnel goes between your home and the VPS, which is almost identical to the connected case above. However the second tunnel runs from your phone through the first tunnel and then terminates inside your home network.
The first/outer tunnel should only provide access to a single port on one server - to allow the second tunnel to be established - other than that it provides no access to your home network. I would envision you using some iptables rules to forward a local port on the VPS down the tunnel.
The second/inner tunnel provides end-to-end encryption from your phone to your home lan.
Given this configuration the outer tunnel doesn't even need to be encrypted, since it is only used to forward one port and all traffic on that port is encrypted. Hence you won't need any keying material on the VPS and even if the VPS was breached the only access that the attacker would be provided would be to one port on your network (which is already publicly exposed).

TL;DR - I doubt that if all you do is use some iptables rules on the VPS the packets will make it through the second NAT.
By using the outer tunnel, it is much more likely that the packets will pass  the second NAT.
